# How to set flat style to NSButton on NSToolbar (to look like NSToolbarItem)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

How to set flat style to NSButton on NSToolbar (to look like NSToolbarItem).
[image]

For instance, the last toolbar item in the figure (Pointer) should look like other toolbar items. Currently it has border with shadow. How to make it flat. Prefered language Objective-C.

Need to find proper styles to adjust NSButton to look like NSToolbarItem. NSButton is created on this way:

```
- (instancetype)initWithImage:(NSImage*) image
{
    self = [super init];
    [super setImage:image];
    //[super setBordered:NO];
    popover = nil;
    return self;
}
```

If I include code with [super setBordered:NO]; then I get proper visuals, however when I set new image it doesn't refresh. Only after second clicking new image is visible.  So, after calling

```
[button setImage:newImage];
```

button doesn't refresh. Label is always refreshed.

Comment: Try setting the image on a toolbarItem: [toolbarItem setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:@"xxxx.png"]];

Comment: No, it doesn't help. Same problem.

Comment: The other toolbar items appear to be images and they are just fine.  It is possible to place an NSButton on a toolbar, but it’s more code and functionally it works the same as a toolbarItem with an image.  Please post runnable source code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem that you are describing.  I set a borderless NSButton on the toolbar and changed the button image with no refresh lag.

Comment: Instead of NSButton I've created an instance of NSView and drawing on it myself. It looks great. Thanks for support.